# Hinged rods concepts

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Let's say we have 2 surfaces - rod and a wall which are connected with a hinge.
What I'm struggling to understand is the direction in which reaction forces at a hinge act.
Do they always act perpendicular to the surface in which they're in contact with - why or why not - could someone please help clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you push on an object, it can respond in one of two ways (or a combination of them):

- It can move (accelerate) away
- It can push back

If you push on the end of the rod that is attached to the hinge in any direction, the rod doesn't move away.   The hinge holds that end in place.  Therefore the hinge is able to develop forces to resist the push (reaction forces) in any direction.

Comment: Perhaps you could extend this answer to address torques/moments and rotational acceleration. This would be useful in distinguishing a hinge from a rigid/clamped/glued connection, which also resists pushing in all directions.